# Eclipse Custom Splash Plugin Not Triggering

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, splash-screen

I created a simple eclipse splash screen by extending the `BasicSplashHandler`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.splashHandlers">
  <splashHandler
        class="splash.MySplashHandler"
        id="splash.splashHandler">
  </splashHandler>
  <splashHandlerProductBinding productId="splash.splashHandlerProductBinding"
        splashId="splash.splashHandler">
  </splashHandlerProductBinding>
</extension>
</plugin>
```

FlashHandler Class

```
public class MySplashHandler extends BasicSplashHandler {

  public MySplashHandler() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void init(Shell splash) {
    //To make this more simple, I just print it out for now.
    System.out.println("This doen't triggered");
    super.init(splash);
  }
}
```

But when I run the project as an eclipse application, it still shows the default splash instead of mine. (Above example I removed all my custom UI components.)

Is there anything else to do to activate a custom splash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified that your splash is for a product with id `splash.splashHandlerProductBinding`. This id must match the id of your product declared using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

You must also run the RCP by specifying the product id to run in the Run Configuration.